# I want to completely switch from windows 7 to Linux

Tags: linux, partition, mbr

I am switching from windows to Linux and want to do manual partition. I have a MBR disk.
I want to delete windows 7 so can I delete the system reserved windows partition and the rest of the drive?

Comment: oops, misread ... yes, you can do whatever you want with partitions

Comment: But there's no need to. If you're a Linux newbie then prefer the automatic partitioning offered by the distro installer. In Debian/Ubuntu and derivatives almost all the installers have the "Erase and install..." option, it's all you need.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you don't plan to keep Windows 7, you can erase its partition and any reserved partition it uses, since they would be useless (they have the purpose of restoring Windows in case of serious crashes).

For an inexperienced user, as already said by @ChanganAuto in a comment, it would be much easier to go with automatic partitioning. Just choose the option to use the whole disk, without keeping existing partitions, and you are good to go.